# Docusaurus — How to shift the table of contents

Tags: reactjs, docusaurus

I'm currently working on writing up a case study using docusaurus and the case-study.md file looks like this

[image]

As you can see, the content is on the left, and the table of contents is on the right. By default, the table of contents seems to be pinned to the top of the page. However, I'd like to implement something more similar to this:

[image]

In this example, the table of contents would be below the main header. Any idea how to make this work?